# Return JSON List and use on MVC 4 View Page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used JSON to return a list but unsure how to use the returned list on a MVC 4 view page. Is this possible?

View Page

```
var subjectId = value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/JobProfiles/FindJobProfiles/" + subjectId,
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {

        }
    });
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FindJobProfiles(int? subjectId)
        {
            if (subjectId.HasValue)
            {
                Subject subject = subjectRepository.Get(subjectId.Value);
                IList<JobProfile> jobProfiles = jobProfileRepository.GetBySubject(subject.Id, false, false);
                var jobProfileList = from c in jobProfiles select new { Id = c.Id, Title = c.Title };
                return new JsonResult { Data = jobProfileList.ToList() };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

View Page Display

```
foreach (JobProfile job in jobProfiles)
{
    <a href="/JobProfiles/View/@job.Id" title="@job.Title">@job.Title
}
```

The correct data is returned but not sure how to access the list on the view page and display the data.

Comment: How do you want to display it (in a table? in a dropdownlist?). Show the html you want to generate for each item in the collection. And why is this method a POST - it appears to be a GET?

Comment: Added above code. Would like to display in a div tag if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a div to the page for the result or the html element you would like to display it:

```
<div id="results" />
```

Add a success handler that loops the result and appends it:

```
var subjectId = value;
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/JobProfiles/FindJobProfiles/" + subjectId,
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                        $('#results').append('<a href"/JobProfiles/View/' + item.Id +  '" title="' + item.Title +'">' + item.Title + '</a>');
                        });    
                }

            });
```

Comment: Is it possible to add to a div tag?

Comment: @Ros Yes just add a div and use the append method too.

Comment: @Ros Updated per requirements, sorry for any typos not tested.

Comment: @mattytommo I personally blame you, I wish you never got me into this. It's addictive. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assuming, you want to display data in list.
For that you need to have div with some id say target-div in your html page.
Using jquery you can display list in target-div as shown below.

```
success: function (data){
   var markup='<ul>';
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
   {
       markup+='<li>'+ data[i].itemName +'<li>';
       //itemName is key here.
   }
   markup+='</ul>';
   $('#target-div').html(markup);//this will place the list in div.
}
```